# How to convert xlsx file with html code inside to pandas library?

Tags: python, html, excel, pandas

I have some atypical situation. I have an xlsx excel file where I have code in html. If I copy it out and paste it to notepad and open it in browser it will return nice database. But how can I do it using code? I want to input it to pandas in next lines of codes.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please note that SO is not a free coding service - please provide your code and where you stucking with.

Comment: Please add a Minimal, Reproducible Example that illustrates your issue - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can save your html file and then use BeautifulSoup to read the data from it.

So it would be something like:

```
url = "C:\example.html"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
```

Comment: How can i copy content of that file to html and when i did it manually still have got an error:     import urllib2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
'
I had imported:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
'

Comment: Here is a more complete code that should get you started on parsing your HTML and then adding the data you need into Pandas DF.  `import pandas as pd
import requests # Import the library for sending requests to the server
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # Import the library for webpage parsing
URL='.html'
req = requests.get(URL) # GET-request
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')`